# Go not found in Docker-based Jenkins agent

Tags: docker, go, jenkins, alpine-linux

I have created a Docker-based Jenkins agent that uses `docker:stable-dind` (which is based on Alpine 3.10) as its base. [Full Dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/mw6HQEV5).

In the Dockerfile I install Go: `RUN apk add go`

When running locally, e.g. `go version`, `go env GOROOT`, etc... I get results, e.g. `1.12.6`, `/usr/lib/go`.

I then attempt using this agent in Jenkins, and print `env` to verify the above environment variables are, but they not there and also `go version` fails`.

So, I update the Docker agent template in Jenkins with:

- `GOROOT`: `/usr/lib/go`
- `PATH`:`/bin/sonar-scanner/bin/:/usr/local/bin:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH`

Now when checking `env` they are there...

```
GOROOT=/usr/lib/go
PATH=/bin/sonar-scanner/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/lib/go/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
GOPATH=/home/jenkins/workspace/go test
```

... but `go version` still fails.

`GOPATH` is set to the current `$WORKSPACE` as that's where I will clone the Go project source if this actually works.

This is the Jenkins job:

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'cli-agent'
  }

  stages {
    stage ("test") {
      steps {
        script {
          withEnv(["GOPATH=${WORKSPACE}"]) {
             sh """
                env
                go version
             """
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `GOPATH=/home/jenkins/workspace/go test` the trailing ` test` looks suspicious.

Comment: That was it. sigh... removed the spaces...